# How to get zip file from node server to react-native client

Tags: node.js, react-native, zip, buffer, unzip

I trying to send a zip file from the node server to the react-native client.
In the server, I'm using 'adm-zip' and send buffer to the client.
I can't find a way to save and unzip the file in the client.

here is my code in the node server:

```
const zip = new AdmZip();
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
     zip.addLocalFile(files[i].path);
}
const downloadName = `zipFiles.zip`;
const data = zip.toBuffer();
// save file zip in root directory
        
zip.writeZip(`${baseUrl.filesBaseUrl}${req.params.screenId}/${req.params.userId}/${downloadName}`);

// code to download zip file
res.set('Content-Type','application/octet-stream');
res.set('Content-Disposition',`attachment; filename=${downloadName}`);
res.set('Content-Length',data.length);
res.send(data);
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use react-native lib `react-native-fetch-blob` :

```
import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob';
...
RNFetchBlob.config({
fileCache : true,
path: path + '/filename'})
.fetch('GET','URL ')
.progress((chunks, total) => {console.log('process', chunks / total)})
.then((res) => {
        console.log('The file saved to ', res.path());
});
```

And to unzip you can use `react-native-zip-archive` :

```
import { zip, unzip, unzipAssets, subscribe } from 'react-native-zip-archive'

const targetPath = `${DocumentDirectoryPath}/myFile.zip`
const sourcePath = DocumentDirectoryPath

zip(sourcePath, targetPath)
.then((path) => {
  console.log(`zip completed at ${path}`)
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error)
})
```

For more details check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-zip-archive).

Comment: I've tried your way but because of some reasons I got an error in compilation time, I forget to mention I'm using expo and develop with vs code in mac. in addition -  i can't use 'react-native-zip-archive' , not found the module :\

Comment: I always get this error : Null is not an object (evaluating 'RNFetchBlob.DocumentDir')

Comment: you need to install these modules. check here for `react-native-fetch-blob` [https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fetch-blob]